# Como copiar una columna de una tabla en base con SQL a otra tabla vacía

Tags: jquery, sql, base-de-datos

Crea una nueva tabla vacía que se llame PIEDRAS a partir de la tabla MINERALES
con todos sus campos e introduce en ella todos los minerales que sean piedras
(campo PIEDRA=TRUE).
Tengo que hacer eso he probado muchas cosas pero no encuentro la sintaxis en SQL de libreoffice BASE esto ha sido lo último que he probado[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo he usado este y no me da error, podrías intentarlo

`INSERT INTO Nombre_tabla_destino (Nombre_columna) SELECT Nombre_columna_origen FROM Nombre_tabla_origen;`

Comment: INSERT INTO [PIEDRAS] (PIEDRA)
SELECT [PIEDRA]
FROM [MINERALES]
Lo escribo así o como?

Comment: Lo puse de esa manera porque así solo reemplazas Nombre_tabla_destino por el nombre de tu tabla real, en todo caso si tienes almacenado un campo con los valores TRUE o FALSE, solo añades `WHERE Nombre_columna = TRUE` espero te sirva

Comment: Sabes cómo es la sintax en Libreoffice de base, es que por lo que he estado viendo es diferente he probado con esto INSERT INTO [PIEDRAS] (PIEDRA)
SELECT [PIEDRA]
FROM [MINERALES]
WHERE [PIEDRA] = 'TRUE'

Comment: Por el error que te da y porque SQL deberia ser SQL aquí y en la China, diria que te sobran los corchetes `[]`en todas las partes de tus consultas. Prueba sin ellos y creo que empezaras a conseguir resultados y saltarte errores.